# Return function results without echo PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to auto populate a set of pages with the content automatically generated by what is contained in a set folder structure.

I have found some code that is most of the way to what I am after however I am trying to modify it so that it is a function that can be called more than once with different folders.
The original code used a simple echo and was not a function.

I have edited it and made it a function but am getting stuck trying to figure out how to have the function return all of the results within the specified folder.

I am using this function:

```
    function getDirContents($dir) {
      date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Brisbane");
      $hide = ".";
      if (!isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) || $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "" || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,2) == ".." || strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "..")) {
          $currdir = "$dir";
      } else {
          $currdir = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
      }
      if ($currdir == "$dir") {
          $label = "Root";
        } else {
          $path = explode('/', $currdir);
          $label = $path[count($path)-1]; 
      }
      // Opens directory
      $myDirectory = opendir($currdir);
      // Gets each entry
      while ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
          $dirArray[] = $entryName;
      }
      // Closes directory
      closedir($myDirectory);
      // Counts elements in array
      $indexCount = count($dirArray);
      // Sorts files
      //sort($dirArray);
      // Loops through the array of files
      for ($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
          // Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
          if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide ) {
              // Resets Variables
              $favicon = "";
              $class = "file";
              // Gets File Names
              $name = $dirArray[$index];
              $namehref = ($currdir == "." ? "" : $currdir . '/') . $dirArray[$index];
              $fullname = $currdir . '/' . $dirArray[$index];
              // Gets Date Modified
              $modtime = date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($fullname));
              $timekey = date("YmdHis", filemtime($fullname));
              // Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
              if (is_dir($currdir . '/' . $dirArray[$index])) {
                  $extn = "&lt;Directory&gt;";
                  $size = "&lt;Directory&gt;";
                  $sizekey = "0";
                  $class = "dir";
                  // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
                  if (file_exists("$namehref/favicon.ico")) {
                      $favicon = " style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon.ico);'";
                      $extn = "&lt;Website&gt;";
                  }
                  // Cleans up . and .. directories
                  if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon.ico);'";}
                  if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}

                  if ($currdir == "." && $dirArray[$index] == "..")
                      $namehref = "";
                  elseif ($dirArray[$index] == "..") {
                      $dirs = explode('/', $currdir);
                      unset($dirs[count($dirs) - 1]);
                      $prevdir = implode('/', $dirs);
                      $namehref = '?' . $prevdir;
                  }
                  else
                      $namehref = '?' . $namehref;
              }
              // File-only operations
              else {
                  // Gets file extension
                  $extn = pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                  // Prettifies file type
                  switch ($extn){
                      case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
                      case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
                      case "jpeg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
                      case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
                      case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
                      case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

                      case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
                      case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
                      case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                      //case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                      case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                      case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                      case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
                      case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
                      case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

                      case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
                      case "xls": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
                      case "xlsx": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
                      case "doc": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;
                      case "docx": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;

                      //case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
                      case "htaccess": $extn="Apache Config File"; break;
                      case "exe": $extn="Windows Executable"; break;

                      default: if($extn!=""){$extn=strtoupper($extn);} else{$extn="Unknown";} break;
                  }
                  // Gets and cleans up file size
                  $size = pretty_filesize($fullname);
                  $sizekey = filesize($fullname);

               }
              $row = "<td><a href='$namehref'>$name ($extn, $size)</a>    </td>";
              return $row;   
        }
      }
    }
```

And then calling it with a variable like so

```
 $Term1 = getDirContents('myFolder/Structure/');
 echo $term1;
```

This prints out the first file in the folder however I can not for the life of me figure out how to get it to list them all.

My understanding is that when you use return in a function it stops the function, shouldn't the for loop it is within re-run however?

I feel like there is something really basic I am missing here so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: First thing to do is move the `return` statement out of the loop. You'll also want to append to your result (`$row`) instead of directly assigning. I suggest you use an array

Comment: Instead of calling return within the loop, append `$row` to another variable (e.g. `$return`) and return that variable after the loop!

Comment: I think concenating a string (`$return .= $row`) is easier here than using an array

Comment: @wolfgangwalther care to elaborate? It's as simple as `$return[] = $row` and it better managed in memory

Comment: Because the function is apparently expected to return a string. Using an array, you would have to join that array into a single string before returning anyways.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther again, simple `return implode(PHP_EOL, $return)` or just return the array. OP might want to split it into separate table rows which would be quite difficult with a single string.

Comment: @Phil I guess 'simple' depends on the users skill level, as well. While both of them might be straightforward to us, I think `$return .= $row; ... return $return;` is easier to understand, than `$return[] = $row; ... return implode(PHP_EOL, $return);`
Using an array, however, would correctly set newlines, which would not be the case otherwise. Implementing this (without leading or trailing new lines) would probably make the string version harder to understand...

Comment: @wolfgangwalther yes, it is simple. Why would you dumb it down, regardless of skill level?

Comment: @Phil Not necessarily dumbing that down, but the question / problem is basically about understanding how to use a loop and return from the function, more towards flow control. Just focusing on that with easier to read / understand code.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther why is using string concatenation *easier to read / understand*? This whole attitude of *"oh don't do that, it's not as easy to read / understand"* is just plain stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple fix for this would be to change how you assign the table row strings to append the next row to the holding variable `$row` (with `.=`), and then move the `return` outside the loop.

I'm not going to copy the whole of your code, but the final few lines would look like this;

```
          $row .= "<td><a href='$namehref'>$name ($extn, $size)</a>    </td>";
          // deleted 'return $row;' and moved to below
    }
  }
  return $row;
}
```

Hope this helps.

PS: As we are appending strings to `$row`, it is good practice to initialize it at the top of your function in order to ensure there isn't a value for `$row` already in memory. To do this, simply write `$row = '';` (ie, set it to a blank string).

Comment: You should also initialise the `$row` variable above the loop, otherwise this will trigger an `E_NOTICE` level error on the first loop iteration

Comment: @Phil Interesting. I've never had that problem, and that's with all error reporting turned on - but I bow to your better judgement.

Comment: Seriously? You sure you're not running error reporting with `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`? See example here ~ https://eval.in/211142

Comment: @Phil Yes, but I do run on a shared server (for historical reasons) so perhaps some notices are still suppressed. Having said that, it is only a notice. If you aren't using `$row` in a script before including this file then there's no problem (and as this is inside a function there should be no problem at all), but I take your point.

Comment: Oooh you guys are amazing! Thank you soooo much!! Also fyi it did throw an error until I added a '$row' variable above the loop so thank you Phil and worldofjr

Comment: *"Having said that, it is only a notice."* ~ that's got to be the worst thing I've read all day. As for the rest of your comment, it doesn't make any sense. The best idea would be to write code that doesn't trigger errors.